# NTP (NTPSec-1.2.2) client is able to sync time from NTP server even if the server does not switches from candidate to become system peer

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I have a NTP setup (client-server association) where on the client side, I have below lines(among others) in ntp.conf:

```
# This should be maxclock 7, but the pool entries count towards maxclock.
tos maxclock 11

# Comment this out if you have a refclock and want it to be able to discipline
# the clock by itself (e.g. if the system is not connected to the network).
tos minclock 4 minsane 3

server <NTP server IP addr>
```

Since, I have provided just one NTP server & since [minsane](https://docs.ntpsec.org/latest/ntp_conf.html) value is 3, the server is selected as a candidate for the clock select algorithm but does NOT become the system peer. However, I see that time is still getting synchronized eventually after sometime. I am unable to understand this behavior. I delayed time on the client side by 30 secs & it took 4+ hours to sync. O/p from "timedatectl" cmd also shows System Clock as synchronized. However, from the ntpq program, output of the rv command shows the system status word as:

```
status=c016 leap_alarm, sync_unspec, 1 event, restart,
```

There is of course GAP in my understanding & if someone can help. Thanks in advance

minsane definition according to NTPSec manual:

```
This is the minimum number of candidates available to the clock selection algorithm in order to produce one or more truechimers for the clustering algorithm. If fewer than this number are available, the clock is undisciplined and allowed to run free.
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the way ntpsec generates the config file (at least on debian and ubuntu). The default value for `minsane` is `1`. The `minsane 3` prevents the server from synchronizing the time if fewer servers are set.

The fix should be to remove the tos lines and go with the defaults, or change `minsane 3` to `minsane 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I did a fresh install of a Linux OS (latest version)

Installed NTPsec and have been fine tuning it since.
In the `/etc/ntpsec/ntp.conf`, I commented out the servers and added new lines with nts servers used when the computer is online.

Added another line with my ntp server TF-NTP-LITE, ip address ,this being used when computer offline.
The computer is connected directly to the ntp server TF-NTP-LITE via ethernet cable.
When offline there was a + sign next to my ntp server.
Looking for information on this ,it should have been an asterisk against it
.
Came across this post and followed your recommendation to change `minsane 3` to `minsane 1`.

This solved the problem and now my ntp server shows the correct symbol which should be the asterisk.
Thank you for sharing your info which was extremely helpful.